# C# Edit Txt file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want to add a new line to my txt file. 
I tried to write a new line like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\text.txt",true)) 
{
    file.WriteLine("SOME TEXT");
}
```

In this way it goes to the last line and writes, but if I want to write, for example on the fourth line without deleting the old data, how I can do this? How I can define that this string must be written in the forth line?

Thank for atention.

Answer (score 8):

You may use this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\text.txt").ToList();
lines.Insert(4, "SOME TEXT");
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\text.txt", lines);
```